PSE Advent Calendar 2024 (Day 12): 12 Days of Gaming
This puzzle is part of the Puzzling Stack Exchange Advent Calendar 2024. The accepted answer to this question will be awarded a bounty worth 50 reputation.< Previous Door Next Door >
On the first day of Christmas my true love played with me…

On the second day of Christmas my true love played with me… (8)

On the third day of Christmas my true love played with me… (4,4,2)

On the fourth day of Christmas my true love played with me… (10,4)

On the fifth day of Christmas my true love played with me… (6)
       
 ,      


Possible outcomes (from best to worst):

???
___
___


On the sixth day of Christmas my true love played with me… (3,5)

On the seventh day of Christmas my true love played with me… (8)

On the eighth day of Christmas my true love played with me… (7,5)

On the ninth day of Christmas my true love played with me… (9,7)

On the tenth day of Christmas my true love played with me… (4,7)

On the eleventh day of Christmas my true love played with me… (6)

On the twelfth day of Christmas my true love played with me…


And at the end, what episode of what TV series did we watch?
_ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _ _ _   _ _ _   (17-12-2011)



 All subpuzzles are independent of each other.

 The cards in 1, 6 and 11 are taken from packs of my own design. 2 is technically a (7'1) and 11 technically a French (1'6), but the answer for the former is official and that for the latter is common enough in English-speaking literature on the game.

 For 4: GUKESH IS WORLD CHAMPION!!!

 For 8: 包 (パオ)

 For 10: I am looking for a Chinese player at the Champion of Champions, and why the X and check marks instead of something less verbose?

 For 11: It's not PINKIE and it's not fortune telling either. It is also not a trump.


I suspect this is going to require more [knowledge] than any one solver has at their fingertips, so here's a partial answer that gets about half way there. (Since posting it, astute comments from user39583, Lukas Rotter and M Oehm have got us further. There are still some gaps.)
1 (card game; (_____)_) solved

 This seems to be (confirmed by other evidence) some variant of (HEART)S but I don't know of one where the QS specifically scores 0. (There are variants that don't treat the QS specially at all, and ones where it scores 13, and ones where it scores 13 unless you also have all the hearts.)

2 (weird game image with French flag; 8) solved

 This is from Pokemon X or Pokemon Y (I'm not sure of the exact relationship between those). I think the character in the image is called Calem; they're standing in front of the "ultimate weapon" emerging from beneath the small town of Geosenge. And it turns out (thanks to M Oehm for finding this) that in the French version of these games the town is called CROMLAC'H instead.

3 (three cards; 4 4 2) possibly solved

 The game is Jass, the suit is "Rosen", the odd leftmost card ("Under") is, I believe, the same thing as the Jass (cf. English "Jack"), though curiously that name isn't actually used. If roses are the trump suit then this is the highest card in the game -- and in that case the 9 of roses, which comes next, is the second-highest. The third-highest is then the ace of roses, and despite appearances I think that's what the third card shown is. The names of these three cards are PUUR, NELL, AS and perhaps that is our 4 4 2. From the final extraction we know that the last letter of this answer must be S, which this would be consistent with.

4 (chess; 10 4) solved

 This shows a draw by threefold repetition, which one could also call a REPETITION DRAW. [OP note: The position is from Game 2 of the 2024 World Chess Championship.]

5 (unusual script; 6) solved

 This is a Shavian transcription of a couple of lines from a section of Alexander Pope's poem The Rape of the Lock involving a game of Ombre. In that game there are three possible outcomes, best to worst: Sacada, Puesta, Codille. If I am understanding the question correctly, what we need is SACADA.

6 (card game; 3 5) solved

 This turns out (thanks to user39583 for pointing it out in comments) to be a reference to a specific story involving this exact hand and these exact words and the poker player STU UNGAR.

7 (pixels; 8) solved

 This is an instance of Conway's game of Life; it shows one state of a period-113 oscillator called NIHONIUM. [OP note: I discovered this.]

8 (16,000; 7 5) solved

 The game is mahjong; on the basis of the scoring I think specifically Japanese mahjong. A late-given hint points us at the "rule of pao", also called SEKININ BARAI; I don't know anything to speak of about the game but a webpage about this rule includes at least one sample hand that to my ignorant eye looks similar to the one shown in the question.

9 (four-player card game; 9 7) solved

 This is a game of contract bridge; the marked bid of 2C is an instance of the convention called CHECKBACK STAYMAN.

10 (flags, rocket, checkmarks; 4 7) solved

 The flags at the top are of England, Northern Ireland, and Wales. The flag at the left is China. This is about snooker player XIAO GUODONG who at the 2024 Champion of Champions tournament beat Ronnie "The Rocket" O'Sullivan 4-3, Mark Selby (from England) 6-5, and Mark Allen (from Northern Ireland) 6-3, but lost 10-6 to Mark Williams (from Wales) in the final. (The check_marks_ are in honour of three of his four opponents' forenames.)

11 (playing card; 6) solved

 [OP note after answer was accepted] Daniel S found that EXCUSE is the answer – aka the Fool, it excuses the one who plays it from following suit or trumping in tarot.

 This is part of an entire MLP tarot deck I designed, then printed out in June 2024.

12 (woman in dress; __(__) ______) solved

 This is some of the artwork from the game LO(VE) LETTER

What about the final extraction? Well, to begin with

 we need 17 letters from 12 answers. The obvious way to get them is to take one letter from each answer except that for the two with more complicated enumerations we take whatever's in the parentheses. If we take the first letter from each other answer we get HEART.. RS.N.C. .VE which doesn't look promising.

But Lukas Rotter found

 that there was a MLP episode called Hearth's Warming Eve broadcast on that date. That fits with the "()" answers [OP note: and the Christmas theme – Hearth's Warming is the pony equivalent of Christmas, and it's my favourite episode of MLPFIM!] but not at all with the others. But for the ones we have guesses for, the last rather than first letter fits, as M Oehm observes in comments.

Credit where due: user39583, Lukas Rotter and M Oehm all solved some things; if you like this answer, consider going and upvoting something good of theirs as well or instead. 1357924680a and Fitchivalry independently got a couple of things I reached by different routes (and got there before me, had I been paying attention) so they should have been part of how this answer got the way it is but happened not to be :-).

6 is rot13(Fgh Hatne) (see the last paragraph here).

rot13(Gur svany nafjre vf cebonoyl Urneguf Jnezvat Rir, tvira BC fbzrgvzrf unf ZYC ersreraprf va gurve chmmyrf. Gur bevtvany nveqngr svgf)

Good find, @LukasRotter. That's very lilkely it. And that means that Gareth's answers so far and the suggestion in user39583's comment are good, because in answers without brackets, one should take the rot13(ynfg yrggre).

(The Pokémon village with the mehirs is called something else in French.)

I think that #10 is this snooker player. I don't know what the rocket means, but the ticks and crosses might be either something to do with performance in the English/Welsh/NI Opens or outcomes of individual matches against players from those countries. (But I can't see what exactly. There seem to be a lot of Welsh snooker players, but not so many from NI, basen on mousing over the links in the wiki article.)

@MOehm – only 8, 10 and 11 are wrong now.

@ParclyTaxel to be explicit, 8 is not rot13(FUVTREH NXNTV) and 11 is not rot13(whfg CVAXVR)? And when you say 10 (which has no proposed answer in the actual answer) is wrong, do you mean that M Oehm's latest suggestion for it is wrong? Sorry to be dim.

I mean, 8 and 11 are wrong, but just that 10 is still unsolved. (But 10 is not Zhao Xintong. Another snooker player from China.)

OK, thanks. Answer updated accordingly. Haven't yet found a suitable Chinese player...

I swear by the name of either Guodong or Yuelong, if this does not get solved, then I am going to cry in fear.. ):}

For the mahjong part the scoring makes me think of the rule called rot13(frxvava onenv) Due to how the scoring penalty is shared.

11 vf na Y’RKPHFR pneq sebz gnebg uggcf://se.z.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Rkphfr
